# How to get xml content from xml node using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have an xml document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Response>
    <Action>Name</Action>
    <Methods>
        <Method name='GetUser' type='online'>
            <Values fieldId='1' name='Login'/>
            <Values fieldId='2' name='Password'/>
        </Method>
        <Method name='CheckUser' type='online'>some text here</Method>
    </Methods>
</Response>
```

I can have many methods > method. Each method has some attributes and some content. Content might be a single line like "some text here" or contain an xml content like:

```
<Values fieldId='1' name='Login'/>
<Values fieldId='2' name='Password'/>
```

A piece of parse code is:

```
function() {
    var response = {};
    var methods = [];

    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

    $xml.find("Response").each(function () {
        response.action = $(this).find("Action").text();

        $(this).find("Methods > Method").each(function () {
            methods.push({
                name: $(this).attr("name"),
                type: $(this).attr("type"),
                innerText: $(this).text()
            });
        });
    });

    response.methods = methods;

    return response;
}
```

but $(this).text() returns only text but not xml. How can i get an xml string of "Method" content?